# create three SVG circles in the center of browser using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am trying to create three SVG circles with the center point of all the circles to be placed at the center of the browser by using Javascript. And I am able to calculate the center point of any browser using window.innerWidth property in Javascript, but the problem is the circle's center is not meeting the browser's center. The main objective of calculating the browser size is to place the circles in the center with the

```js
function draw_circle() {
  var demo = SVG('circle_1');
  var w = window.innerWidth;
  var h = window.innerHeight;
  
  var x1 = w/3.2;
  var y1 = h/6.2;
  
  var x2 = w/2.85;
  var y2 = h/3.95;
  
  var x3 = w/2.1;
  var y3 = h/2;
  
  demo
    .circle(500)
    .attr({ fill: '#fafafa ' })
    .stroke({ width: 3 })
    .x(x1).y(y1)
  ;
  
  demo
    .circle(395)
    .attr({ fill: '#fafafa ' })
    .stroke({ width: 3 })
    .x(x2)
    .y(y2)
  ;
  
  demo
    .circle(50)
    .attr({ fill: '#fafafa ' })
    .stroke({ width: 3 })
    .x(x3)
    .y(y3)
  ;
}

document
  .addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', draw_circle)
;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.3.6/svg.min.js"></script>

<div id="circle_1"></div>
```

The expected output screenshot same proportions:

[image]
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`circle.size  / 2` is necessary because the origin of an element is the `top-left vertex`.

```js
function DrawCirclesCtrl() {
  var svg = SVG('Circles');
  
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  
  var x = window.innerWidth / 2 ;
  var y = window.innerHeight / 2 ;
  
  var circles = [
    { 
      size: x / 2, bg: '#fafafa', borderSize: 3
    },
    { 
      size: x / 2.5, bg: '#fafafa', borderSize: 3
    },
    { 
      size: x / 5, bg: '#fafafa', borderSize: 3
    }
  ]
  .map(function(circle) {

    return svg
      .circle(circle.size)
      .attr({ fill: circle.bg })
      .stroke({ width: circle.borderSize })
      .x(x - (circle.size / 2))
      .y(y - (circle.size / 2))
    ;
  });
  
}

document
  .addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', DrawCirclesCtrl)
;
```

```css
#Circles {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/svg.js/2.3.6/svg.min.js"></script>


<div id="Circles"></div>
```